# Biodegradable paint for short term use

Tags: diy, biodegradable-waste, safe-chemicals

I attended a protest against the TPPA today and found myself wondering about what biodegradable paint might work nicely for short term use, such as for a cardboard placard. A similar use for such paint might be for low-cost business signs, such as a small orchard shop (locally, these tend to have prices advertised on the road side for seasonal produce that's good value at the time).

What sort of non-toxic paint might be appropriate? Bonus points if it's something that could be made with ingredients commonly found around the home.

Let's assume that it doesn't matter if the paint isn't waterproof.

Comment: 'old school' paints using some natural pigment and a natural glue, like egg white are still used today by artists. I assume you look for something that's not learning a (small) craft of its own, which the preparation of paints may well be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be milk paint.

http://www.milkpaint.com/

Milk Paint receives USDA Biobased Certification

Safe for MCS, Hospitals, Children's things and the Environment